# socket.emit() error handling with socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I am using

```
$('btn').click(function() {
    socket.emit('load more', function (objs) {
        // do something
    });
});
```

on the client to get objects from the server.

But sometimes the connection is lost and nothing happens. How can I make error handling such that I can tell the user that the server doesn't answer instead of letting nothing happen as it is now?

## Edit

So what I want is something like

```
$('btn').click(function() {
    var emit = socket.emit('load more', function (objs) {
        // do something
    });

    if (!emit) {
        console.log("It didn't work. Maybe you lost connection or the server is not running.");
    }
});
```

I do know that I cannot do this, but would it be possible using promises or something?

Comment: Why not use `socket.on('error', function())`

Comment: or something like `socket.on('disconnect', function() {});` , `socket.connected`, `socket.disconnected`

Comment: because i don't want to tell the user that the he/she is disconnected if he/she doesn't do anything that triggers a websocket

Comment: You want to tell the user whether he/she is disconnected or not? Because from your question you said that you wanted to tell the user that the server doesn't answer.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I still mean that I only want to tell the user if the socket.emit() worked and the server answered. So I don't want to listen for any errors. I just want to validate after the click event whether everything worked as it should

Answer (score 1):

Second argument to `emit` is the data that we need to pass on the event `'load more'`.

If you just want to server to let know that you need data, without passing any extra info, just do `socket.emit('load more')`. In server, listen for event `'load more'` and send data to client with particular `event-name`. In Client, listen for the event `'event-name'` and receive data in callback like,

```
socket.on('event-name', function(data_from_server){
    //do something
});
```

If you want to handle the case, where server not sends any data then wait for some time after sending the event `'load mode'` and handle it.

Comment: I don't think I need to listen for even from server. By passing a function in `socket.emit`, I can just send the data back to the client from the server. But I don't know how to handle it when the websocket wasn't sent.

Comment: Why don't you have a flag like 'socketValid` and disable it when `disconnect` or `error` event emitted on it? when user tries to load data, check the flag and notify user. Or whenever you want to send an event through the socket check for it's status using the property `socket.connected` and decide accordingly. If the socket is active/valid, the message always goes to server since it built on top of TCP, I believe